# How to have consistent cursor size on HiDPI?

Tags: i3, cursor, high-dpi, xcursor

So, I'm on a HiDPI machine (XPS 9370) and using the Adwaita cursor; this is on a fresh install of Antergos w/ i3 for context.

I've been playing around with some settings for adapting to HiDPI, but I realized that my cursor changes size depending on what application it is hovering on. Whereas when not hovering over any application or hovering over a few, it may be sized appropriately for the display, but, say when hovering over termite or Firefox, it will decrease to a fraction of the size and become barely visible.

How do I make the cursor size consistent across the entire system?

Xcursor.size does not seem to affect the cursor sizes in the programs I listed.

Comment: are you loading your .Xresources file with xrdb every time you start i3?  what if you add Xcursor.size: xx into your .Xresources file and run xrxb ~/.Xresources during run time?

Comment: @bgregs Sorry, I was unclear. Xcursor.size doesn’t affect (GTK?) programs like Firefox and termite.

Comment: Yeah, now that I wrote that comment, I’m feeling really dumb.

Answer (score 5):

To have GTK 3 programs have a consistent cursor size with X, set `gtk-cursor-theme-size=n` for n as in `Xcursor.size`. The setting can be found in `.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`